# parent folder from path string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string that is a path of the folder

`let mypath = "folder/subfolder/file"`

in general, that can be any length. How can I get the path of the parent (in that case: `let parentname = "folder/subfolder"`) the quickest. I could do:

```
let path_segs = mypath.split("/");
let parentname = "";
for (let i = 0; i < path_segs.length - 2; i++){
    parentname += path_segs[i] + "/";
}
parentname.slice(0, -1);
return parentname;
```

but that seems to be long and inefficient. Is there any better way?

Comment: If your string never ends with a `/`: `mypath.slice(0, mypath.lastIndexOf('/'))`. A shorter version of your array solution would be: `let path_segs = mypath.split("/"); path_segs.pop(); let parentname = path_segs.join('/');` (i.e. simply remove the last element and join the parts again).

Comment: Looks like you're already aware of the fact that `.slice()` "understands" a negative end. So why the loop? `path_segs.slice(0, -1).join("/")`

Comment: @Andreas good point, I haven't thought about it. I've always only used it for removing last element without really thinking how it works. Shame on me. Thank you!

Comment: @FelixKling thank you! The `lastIndexOf` is the method I was thinking about but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let mypath = "folder/subfolder/file";
const a = mypath.substring(0, mypath.lastIndexOf('/'));
console.log(a);
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that you'll receive unexpected behavior if `mypath` is a folder path and ends with a `/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use path.parse. (Node.js only)

```
const path = require("path");
const somePath = "/some/weird/path";
const parsedPath = path.parse(somePath);
console.log(parsedPath.dir); // it will print /some/weird
```

parsedPath.dir is probably what you are looking for, bonus, it will work with paths in both windows and linux.

Comment: thanks, but I don't use Node, I'm working on strings in the UI.